# Recovering checkboxes values of a complex object in C# MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have a **complex object** in my application, something like:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Link Object1 { get; set; }
    public List<Object2> L_Object2 { get; set; }
    public List<Object3> L_Object3 { get; set; }
    public List<Object4> L_Object4 { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Object1 has this structure:

```
public class Object1
{
    public List<Object1B> L_Perfil;
    // Some other irrelevant params here
}
```

And then Object1B:

```
public class SistemaPerfilLink
{
    public int Id_Object2 { get; set; }
    public int Id_Object3 { get; set; }
    public int Id_Object4 { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then I pass this complex object to the view, and do a `CheckboxFor` for the list of `Object1B`, but when I try to recover the values in the controller i can't get the values of the checkboxes.

All other params are ok, I can't recover only the checkboxes, why?

If I try to recover the params by getting a FormCollection from the view, I can see the values.

Signature of my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel vm, FormCollection collection)
```

Can anyone help me to understand why I can't recover it in my ViewModel object? And how can I fix it to recover it by ViewModel object?

**## UPDATE 1 ##**

Adding the code of the view, just the checkboxes part:

```
@{
    int currentId = 0;
}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Object1.Object1B.Count(); i++)
{
    if (currentId != Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Id_Object2) // If Id changes, start a new group
    {
        currentId = Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Id_Object2;
        // DisplayTextFor here, to start new group
    }
    <label>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Status)
    // Next line is just to display the correct name
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => Model.Object1.FirstOrDefault(model => model.Id_Codigo == Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Id_Perfil).Descricao)</label>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Id_Object2)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Id_Object3)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Object1.Object1B[i].Id_Object4, new { @value = 0})

}
```

**## UPDATE 2 ##**

I've created the same object list in the ViewModel object, and its worked well.
Currently, in my action, I get this list and put it in the list of Object1B, but **I want to find a better solution**.

Comment: Can you post the code for CustomCheckBoxFor? I'm guessing it's not correctly adding the name attribute to the html it generates...

Comment: @LeeBailey Forgive, me... I'm not using CustomCheckBoxFor, just a simple CheckBoxFor. I've updated the question to correct this.